# Поиск в textarea слова # (теги)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var str = '';

function count(str) {
  document.getElementById('b1').innerHTML = str.length;
  var st = str.replace(/\n/g, ' ') + ' ';
  st = st.split(/\s#* \s*/).length;

  document.getElementById('b4').innerHTML = st - 1;
  var st = str.replace(/\n/g, ' ') + ' ';
  st = st.split(/\s* \s*/).length;
  document.getElementById('b5').innerHTML = st - 1;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<textarea onkeyup="str=this.value;count(str);" id="mess" name="mess"></textarea>

<div align="left" style="width:30%;">
  <p>всего символов <b id="b1">0</b>
  </p>

  <p>тегов <b id="b4">0</b>
  </p>
  <p>всего слов <b id="b5">0</b>
  </p>
</div>
```

Вот JS скрипт, в `#b4` должен искать теги `#тег1`, `#тег2` и подсчитывать их количество, как это организовать подскажите?

Количество слов и символов считает правильно, а вот теги не желает(
Работает не правильно(

Вот весь код

Comment: document.getElementById('b1').innerHTML=str.length;
  var st = str.replace(/\n/g,' ') + ' ';
 st = st.split(/\s#* \s*/).length;
Вот кусок дописал выше этой строки
 document.getElementById('b4').innerHTML=str.replace(/#/, "").length;

Но немного не так оно считает(

Comment: если хотите изменить текст вопроса, под вопросом есть пункт - править

Comment: и еще добавьте строку на которой проверяли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно заменить *split* на *match*, а так же поменять регулярное выражение на следующее

```
str.match(/(#[^\s#]+)/g)
```

Пример

```js
var str = '';

function countSymbols(str) {
  return str.length;
}

function countWords(str) {
  var st = str.replace(/\n/g, ' ') + ' ';
  st = st.split(/\s* \s*/).length;
  return st - 1;
}

function countTags(str) {
  var tags = str.match(/(#[^\s#]+)/g);

  return tags && tags.length || 0;
}

function count(str) {
  document.getElementById('b1').innerHTML = countSymbols(str);
  document.getElementById('b4').innerHTML = countTags(str);
  document.getElementById('b5').innerHTML = countWords(str);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<textarea onkeyup="str=this.value;count(str);" id="mess" name="mess"></textarea>

<div align="left" style="width:30%;">
  <p>всего символов <b id="b1">0</b>
  </p>

  <p>тегов <b id="b4">0</b>
  </p>
  <p>всего слов <b id="b5">0</b>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо )Работает